# PHP file can generate correct output but not when called by html file

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

I am new to PHP and JavaScript and I am having a programing issue I cannot solve and need some help with.  I have two files:

iisstart.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showPrinters(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
 } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getprinters.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <select name="printers" onchange="showPrinters(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a state:</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
```

and another file: getprinters.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

 $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','w','w');
 if (!$con) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }

 mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
 $sql="SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Printers WHERE ST = '".$q."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 echo "<select id='city' onchange='SelectCity()'>";
 echo "<option value=''>Select Your City</option>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value='" . $row['City'] . "'>". $row['City']. "</option>";

}
echo "</select>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<script>

function SelectCity()
{
document.write("Hello");

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the problem:

When I run getprinters.php directly, I get the output "Hello" successfully on the webpage after I make a selection from the select options (list generated successfully from MySQL database output).  However, when I run iisstart.htm, which calls getprinter.php, and make a selection from the option list, the onchange='SelectCity()' function won't run - no "Hello" output.

I have done some research online but still can't figure out.  Would you please kindly point me to the correct direction to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Your AJAX handler should only return the content you want to insert into `txtHint.innerHTML`. So you can get rid of the `<DOCTYPE>`, `<html>` and `<body>` tags for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the function `SelectCity()` from file `getprinters.php` to file `iisstart.htm` .Remove HTML ,script tags from `getprinters.php`

```
<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

 $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','w','w');
 if (!$con) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }

 mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
 $sql="SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Printers WHERE ST = '".$q."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 echo "<select id='city' onchange='SelectCity()'>";
 echo "<option value=''>Select Your City</option>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value='" . $row['City'] . "'>". $row['City']. "</option>";

}
echo "</select>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Also add `<div id="txtHint"></div>` to the file `iisstart.htm`

Comment: Wow this is so cool! it works instantly Zakhefron. Thanks a bunch for your help and moving me forward on the project :-)

Comment: A new problem has now:  after moving the SelectCity() function to iisstart.htm file, I cannot use this function to pull data from database based on the selection a user make.  I was hoping to insert lines like the following to find out which option the user make from the choice list:

Comment: document.write("hello!!");
        var x = document.getElementById("city");
        var i = x.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.options[i].text;

Comment: Do you have any examples how I can use a variable to store user's selection and how from iisstart.htm I can interact with the database by using this variable?